# Why do I have no .vdi file

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox on my W10 machine but I need to resize the hard drive.

The instructions explain to do it via the command line, and find the .vdi file

I have no .vdi file.

I navigate to `C:\Users\MyUserName\VirtualBox VMs\MyVm` but there is no .vdi file

I then attempt a search in the computer for `*.vdi` and it returns nothing

How can I create a .vdi file (based upon the VM I have) so I can resize the hard drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the configuration of the VM and go to the storage settings, you should see the hard drive(s) attached to the machine. They are identified by the icon in the following image :[image: VirtualBox storage configuration interface]

When you select that line, you should see a location in the attributes to the left, which will tell you where the virtual drive is on your filesystem. Note that virtualbox supports other virtual hard drives format like VMDK or VHD, and the commands required to resize them may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure thats where VirtualBox is storing all its files?

To view all the files (logs, config and the disk image):

1. Open `VirtualBox`.
2. Select the Virtual Machine for which you want to view the files for.[image: Select The virtual Machine]
3. Right click (or select `Machine` from the menu bar) and select 'Show in File Manager' or similar option.

[image: In File manager, you can view basic log file, appliance and the virtual disk]

This should show you the folder in which all files for said VM is currently stored.

> **Note**: depending on how you configured the VM, the filetype may not be vdi. Check for following extensions: `*.vhd, *.vmdk, *.hdd`.

You can also see the location in the settings under `storage` along with the type:
[image: Settings Under storage]

Answer (score 1):

When the VBox guest is created one is provided with three options as to the underlying type of hard disk formats.  The three options are: *.vdi (virtual box), *.vhd (virtual hard disk), *.vmdk (vmware format). I have to presume that the hard disks were created with a different type. If so, you might be out of luck.